# Replace an array of strings in content for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, str-replace

I'm working on a music blog that provides review scores ranging from 0.0 - 10. Since the authors already developed their system of typing in the score in the content, I'm trying figure out a way to emphasis them better.

Example:

```
"Score: 6.4"
```

returns something like

```
<div class="score">6.4</div>
```

Is there way to do this in an array to put every score possibility down within function.php or on the single.php page. Whatever is cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a regular expression search/replace for the content. Then you can hook it into Wordpress by [creating a plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Creating_a_Plugin) and using the wp add_filter function.

```
function expand_scores($content) {
 return preg_replace('/(score):\s*([\d.]+)/ims', '<div class="score">$1: $2</div>', $content);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'expand_scores');
```

Both the `expand_scores` and the `add_filter` call go into your plugin file. The [the_content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) hook applies the expand_scores function to all post data retrieved from the database before printing.